# Azure functions developing locally - cannot register EventHub triggered function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I want to develop locally my Azure Function App and later publish it to Azure Portal.
I am using Azure Functions Core Tools command line and all my functions are in Node.js
Currently, I managed to download my functions locally and fetch their settings with command:

```
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings
```

So after that my local.settings.json has correct settings values. When I make any changes I am also able to publish them succesfully to Azure Portal.

The problem is now that I have two functions in my app, one is Http Triggered and the second is EventHub triggered.
When I try run locally host with:

```
func host start
```

I get the following output from console:

```
[10.12.2017 13:03:47] Found the following functions:
[10.12.2017 13:03:47] Host.Functions.HttpTriggerJS1
[10.12.2017 13:03:47]
[10.12.2017 13:03:47] Job host started
[10.12.2017 13:03:47] The following 1 functions are in error:
[10.12.2017 13:03:47] EventHubTriggerJS1: The binding type 'eventHubTrigger' is not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
```

And when I try to run locally this EventHubTriggerJS1 function with curl:

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"input":"sample queue data"}' http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/EventHubTriggerJS1
```

then nothing happens, so I guess this is a problem of this trigger registration.
The HttpTriggerJS1 runs perfectly, I can access it under

```
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerJS1
```

So, do you have any idea where might be a problem in configuring? BTW Is it possible to have locally function and connect to the remote EventHub in portal?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce your error on the Version 1.0 runtime.

I reproduced the error in 2.0.  I believe 2.0 does not support event hubs yet, 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Azure-Functions-runtime-2.0-known-issues#functional-gaps

try installing the extensions
`func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs -v 3.0.0-beta4`

<s>Can you provided more detail about your functions, and the steps you took to create them?</s>

HttpTriggerJS1 was created locally and then published to the portal following the steps outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local ?

EventHubTriggerJS1 was created in the portal? in the same Function App?

Do not mix local development with portal development in the same function app. When you create and publish functions from a local project, you should not try to maintain or modify project code in the portal.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reponse.
I have created functions in portal and then I downloaded them locally and tried to run them with `func host start` .I use runtime 1.0, both HttpTriggerJS1 and EventHubTriggerJS1 belong to the same function app. When I run them in portal, both are working fine, however I would like to have local environment, and there only HttpTriggerJS1 is working properly.
After installing suggested extension unfortunately the both Trigger functions are not working. I get a message in console:
https://imgur.com/8uWrZHI

You managed to do it locally, without portal?

Comment: Can you provide your function.json files?
Also check that you copied the app-setting properly, run
`func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings <FunctionAppName>`

Comment: Patrick, thanks for support, I have found the solution. The problem was that I was using new version of azure-function-core-tools@core (runtime 2.0). After removing it and installing runtime 1.0 with `npm install -g azure-function-core-tools`, `func host start` sets up smoothly all functions, eventhub triggered included! Sorry for late response